# JavaScript - Delete Array from Object

Tags: javascript, json

Is it possible to delete an array from an object?  For example, lets say i have an object called response and within it and array called items:

```
var response = { success: false, items:[] };
```

How do i delete 'items' from the response object?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
delete response.items;
```